# The number of matches in a competition 1

Tags: combinatorics

In a competition each player has to play 3 matches , if the number of players is $16$ , then the number of matches of the competition is .....

a) 120

b) 360

c) 150

d) 240

My turn :
The number of matches $= C^{16}_{2} \times 3 $ = $360$
Is it correct ?

Comment: Every match is between two competitors. right?

Comment: I think so , although it is not mentioned in the question ! @Thomas Andrews

Comment: This is not clear.  As it stands, the answer is obviously $24$...not one of the options.  Did you mean to say that "every pair of players must face each other exactly $3$ times" or something like that?

Comment: The answer may be just $3$, if every match involves all $16$ players.

Answer (score 1):

No, the number of matches is $24$.

Since each player plays $3$ matches, there are $48$ man-matches.  But each match generates $2$ man-matches, since each match involves $2$ people.

Therefore, the number of physical matches that will be played is $\frac{48}{2}.$

Comment: I have added the choices given for the answer @user2661923

Comment: @HussienMohamed I don't know how to respond here.  If 1 plays 2, 3 plays 4, ..., 15 plays 16, you have 8 matches.  Then, for every 8 matches played, each player plays once.  $3 \times 8 = 24$.  Is there more information in the problem that is not being shared?  Alternatively, do you detect a flaw in my analysis?